# Unsure on how to get the geomean calculation in the loop to work

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: defining geomean]
[image: the loop]

I defined geomean but when running the code and inputting integers to make the calculation, the output returns that it doesn't recognize geomean. All the other functions work fine. Not sure on what to do for geomean.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Where are your variables *iterable* and *datalist* defined?

Answer (score 0):

The calling function for geo_mean as defined above should be :

```
geo_mean(datalist, iterable)
```

but while calling in the else part you are calling as :

```
geo_mean(iterable, datalist)
```